# Hybrid Application Testing for Appium

Tags: selenium, appium

I worked on Appium using Hybrid Application in java, Mean while the versions are Appium 1.4.0 and Eclipse Mars, Selenium 2.47.0. Dependencies jar files are download from [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), [Appium](http://appium.io/downloads.html).

Here Apk file is used for Hybrid Testing.
Please help me for the Script level.

Comment: Sorry unable to understand your question. Please share what you have done so far and explain briefly.

Comment: My Hybrid app script doesn't work Using new versions of Appium and Selenium jar files. Suggest me for how can i write capabilities and the Which type of jar files import.?

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issues in viewing html elements in our hybrid app. 
We used the following code snippet in our setup() method while setting up capabilities.

Set contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
        System.out.println(contextNames); //prints out something like NATIVE_APP \n WEBVIEW_1

```
    driver.context((String) contextNames.toArray()[1]);
```